# bootstrap-tagsinput not showing autocomplete

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

```
$('#city').tagsinput({
 typeahead: {
 source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
  }
});
<input type="text" id="city">
```

its not showing the autocomplete from the source and there is no error as well. how to load autocomplete with static array data in tagsInput.
Thanks in Advance..
btw you might ask the tagsInput is not initialized properly it is inside ready function() and I also tried running the code form console

Comment: solved: was issue with the version of typeahead version if any meteor users facing same error please use this package:
   ` mrt:bootstrap3-typeahead`